# GPU RAM Memory fragmentation using cupy?

Tags: nvidia, autoencoder, unsupervised-learning, chainer, cupy

I am Training VAE Model on CPU it works well for 1 epoch, since I need to train it more to get good result using GPU is required, I tried training on GPU but it goes Out of Memory. Since, CPU takes 25.375 GB Memory. As it is cleared GPU memory is 12 GB, it will throw Out of memory. So now, I shifted the code to larger Instances having 8 gpu of (12 * 8 GB) memory. So, accordingly the problem of *out of memory* should be solved, Instead it copies all the occupied memory from 1 gpu to all 8 GPU. So, using Multiple GPU is of no use.

I found out the total memory to complete the whole training which is 25.375 GB.
So,using single GPU of 12 GB will throw out of memory. Now, I am using 8 GPU of each 12 GB to solve this problem.

GPU : K80
Chainer : 6.0.0
Cupy    : 6.0.0

```
avg_elbo_loss.to_gpu()
```

above code occupies around 8GB of memory out of 12Gb.
Is there anyway to reduce it or write it that it get reduced ?

I tried to go fo Multiple GPU to solve this problem.

```
   num_gpus =8

   if num_gpus > 0:

    updater = training.updater.ParallelUpdater(
    train_iter,
    optimizer,
    devices={('main' if device == 0 else str(device)): device for 
             device in range(num_gpus)},
)
else:
    updater = training.updater.StandardUpdater(train_iter, optimizer, 
                device=args.gpus)
```

The output is expected from using single GPU .

Comment: Is there anyway to reduce the number of bytes allocated ?

Comment: Iterator and generator has been used since it found to be causing the error.but same error of OOM is faced.